# Insert, Update query on index in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, rdbms

**Which one has better performance among Insert, Update on index key in Postgresql?**

Answer (score 0):

An `insert` statement just needs to add a value to the index. An `update` statement needs to remove the old value from the index and then add the new value to it. So all other things being equal, considering just the modification of the index, the `update` query should be slower.

Comment: Yeah but postgresql uses HOT updates. don't know if update is still slower than insert. Could not find much resource on it.